# How do I return the image from the server?

Tags: node.js, image

Im working on a NodeJS api and I'm mapping some foreign services to get an image.
The problem is, when I do it, I get a very large string (not sure what it is) instead of the image. How do I get the image? If I do this in Postman (without the mapping, consuming the needed services to get the image, it sends me the image alone). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you get Base64 String of image?

Comment: How do I know if it's a base64?, @UtkarshDubey

Comment: It generally starts with `data:image/` tag.

Comment: No. It doesn't start with it.

Comment: can you edit your question and paste that large string.